# MySQL - How to get hostname/IP and which user making hacking attempts to MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

Can anybody please help me out in getting from which hostname/IP and which user is making hacking attempts to MySQL server?
I can see high value for `Aborted_connects` status variable and it's keep on increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html).  As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/communication-errors.html):

> If a client is unable even to connect, the server increments the [`Aborted_connects`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) status variable. Unsuccessful connection attempts can occur for the following reasons:
>
> - A client does not have privileges to connect to a database.
> - A client uses an incorrect password.
> - A connection packet does not contain the right information.
> - It takes more than [`connect_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) seconds to get a connect packet. See [Section 5.1.3, “Server System Variables”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html).
>
> If these kinds of things happen, it might indicate that someone is trying to break into your server! Messages for these types of problems are logged to the general query log if it is enabled.

Comment: I will try this hope this helps as I am using 5.1.36 unlike MySQL 5.5+